# eraseColor on bitmap makes everything black

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, android-image

I have an application in which I have many layers on the imageView. So for one of the specific event I was trying to make uppermost layer removed.

I was trying to use `bitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)` but this lead to complete bitmap turning black. I need to perform the above operation so that the underneath layer is visible. Is there any way I can make the uppermost layer completely transparent or erase using some paint and path (I tried using Paint with clear mode but it was also drawing black line instead of erasing the top layer).

Comment: Is the `ImageView` set on a black background? `Bitmap.eraseColor(int) fills the bitmap's pixels with the specified Color`. So, basically, makes the ImageView see-through (when using Color.TRANSPARENT). Perhaps, you should look into `Bitmap.setPixels(int[], int, int, int, int, int, int)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make it transparent not remove from stack use

```
((View)yourBitmap).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

if you want to remove it completely, then use;

```
((View)yourBitmap).setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

If you will not use that bitmap anymore I suggest to use latter, since it will remove bitmap from stack, you won't have an extra `Bitmap` drawing on your rendering and it will increase performance as well.

Comment: I am more interested in knowing why the eraseColor thing is not working since it is also creating another problem when i try to make specific pixels transparent on the layer and not the whole view.

Comment: but your question mentions you want to know "Is there any way I can make the uppermost layer completely transparent",